# UIRotationGestureRecognizer to snap on right angles

Tags: ios, swift, math, uiview, rotation

I am trying to have this rotation mechanism to snap on right angles, e.g.  when the user gets close to (85 to 95 degrees) it automatically snaps to 90 degrees until he moves away from 85 or 95 degrees.

```
var lastRotation = CGFloat()
func rotateAction(sender:UIRotationGestureRecognizer){


    let currentTransform = sender.view?.transform
    let rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - sender.rotation)
    let newTransform = currentTransform!.rotated(by: rotation)

    let radians = atan2f(Float(sender.view!.transform.b), Float(sender.view!.transform.a))
    let degrees = radians * (180 / .pi)

    sender.view?.transform = newTransform
    lastRotation = sender.rotation
    if sender.state == .ended {
        lastRotation = 0.0;
    }

    // The if statement works correctly when reaching the angles
    if degrees > -95 && degrees < -85 {

    }
    else if degrees > -185 && degrees < -175 {

    }
    else if degrees > -275 && degrees < -265 {

    }
    else if degrees > -5 && degrees < 5 {  
        // So I tried this but it does not seem right, it always pushed it away from angle 0
        lastRotation = CGFloat(0.0 - radians)
    }

}
```

Comment: I would print out your math as you are going - degrees actually comes out to between -180...0...180...-180 etc

Comment: Also, keep in mind sender.rotation is additive, meaning if you go around a bunch of times in the same direction, it will be 360, 720, 1080 (whatever that is in rads). As you go the other way, that number will go lower.

Answer (score 0):

The math is not commiserate with the checks you are doing (the degrees variable goes: -180...0...180 -> -180...0 etc).

The other problem is that sender.rotation is cumulative, meaning it will keep adding or subtracting rads as you rotate.

Once the other math is fixed, I would suggest something akin to the following for checking the "snaps".

```
    let rad = fabs(sender.rotation.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2 * CGFloat.pi))

    print("rotation", sender.rotation, degrees, rad)

    switch rad {
    case 1.48353...1.65806 :
        print("do things")
    case 3.05433...3.22886 :
        print("do things")
    case 4.62512...4.79966 :
        print("do things")
    case 0...0.0872665 :
        print("this is check one of 2")
    case 6.19592...6.28319 :
        print("this is check two of 2")
    default:
        print("do other things")
    }
```

EDIT: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirotationgesturerecognizer/1624337-rotation

Comment: This should clamp radians in the [-2π,2π] range first. `if (currentRotation > 2.0*π || currentRotation < -2.0*π) {currentRotation = fmodf(currentRotation, (2.0*π));}`. .... Also doesn't handle [-2π,0] if view was rotated counterclockwise

Answer (score 0):

Objective-c which can be easily ported

```
if (DISTANCE(rotationValue, round(rotationValue/(π/2.0))*(π/2.0)) < 0.05) {
    rotationValue = round(rotationValue/(π/2.0))*(π/2.0);//90º snapped
}
```

Utilizes the following macros, optionally:

```
#define π 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288 
#define DISTANCE(__valueOne, __valueTwo) ((((__valueOne)-(__valueTwo))>=0)?((__valueOne)-(__valueTwo)):((__valueTwo)-(__valueOne)))
```